# socat does not honor sourceport option

Tags: udp, socat, broadcast

I am trying to send a udp packet from a specific port:

```bash
$ echo hello | socat - UDP-DATAGRAM:192.168.1.255:11111,broadcast,sourceport=22222
```

But a random port is used instead:

```bash
# tcpdump -vvvv -ttttt -nienp0s31f6 udp
tcpdump: listening on enp0s31f6, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
 00:00:00.000000 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 40649, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 34)
    192.168.1.17.35829 > 192.168.1.255.11111: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 6
```

**How can I send a (broadcast) udp packet from a specific port?**

N.B. I also tried sending a unicast udp packet with socat, but `sourceport` wasn't honored there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `bind` option instead of `sourceport`:

```
$ echo hello | socat - UDP-DATAGRAM:192.168.1.255:11111,broadcast,bind=:22222
```

I'm not sure why `sourceport` doesn't work in this case, since it clearly does for e.g. `UDP-CONNECT`...but it's also not clear why there's a separate `sourceport` option when `bind` already does the same thing.

Comment: You're the man!